# Java Library for Drag and Drop, and Diagram Draw Support

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, desktop-application, diagram

I am working on a software where I need to define items to be dragged and dropped onto a blank screen. The item properties are set within the screen, and could also be removed.

It is similar to what the UML drawing applications do. However, I want this for a project to control devices where device icons are on one side of the screen and the user will be able to drag and drop these icons on the screen, connect them together, configure them ...etc.

Is there any specific Java library that implements this? If not, do you suggest other programming languages that have good libraries that can aid with that particular implementation?

**NOTE:** This is a desktop application currently. However, suggestions for only online applications are welcome. Thank You,

Comment: Which Java UI library are you using? Swing?

Comment: @D.R. I haven't started the project yet, but I think if I use jave, I will go for Swing. Otherwise I might just go with C# Windows Forms

Comment: You can look at `java.awt.datatransfer` package in java..http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/package-summary.html

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's not what he was looking for.

Comment: You want to Develop that software for Drag and Drop? or you just want a software that supports Drag and Drop?

Comment: a software that supports diagram connections and drag drop. So a UML drawing-like software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Swing already comes with Drag&Drop support, however, no links/etc.

You can have a look at the Eclipse GEF project at http://www.eclipse.org/gef/ - a framework built for creating graphical editors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try checking out Eclipse's GMF framework.  I know it's been used in a few commercial wireframing products http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/gmp/.

Comment: how is GMF different from GEF?

Comment: No difference, GEF is a part of GMF

Answer (score 1):

Window builder from google looks to be a far easier tool to use. https://developers.google.com/java-dev-tools/wbpro/

Comment: does Windows Builder have support for graphical editing ?

Comment: I think it does, though i have not used it for that purpose.